# How to prevent shop manager to edit or delete other shop manager products?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an website installed WordPress using woocommerce. Any one can register here as a shop manager. They can post there own products. I want that they can only see their own products and order menu under the 'Products' menu. What will be the function actually. I removed woocomerce menu from the main menu by usi this function.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
function remove_menus(){

// If the current user is not an admin
if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {

    remove_menu_page( 'woocommerce' ); // WooCommerce admin menu slug

}
 }
```

What will be the function for the 
 Products
   -----Add Products 
   -----Orders 
   -----Products 
Shop manager can only see like this.
Any idea Please.

Comment: I don't think woocommerce is intended for making a multi-tenant store.

Comment: How can I make like that i want?

Comment: Hire a developer who knows how?

Comment: Any source to learn it?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Show only posts and media related to logged in author
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_set_only_author' );
function query_set_only_author( $wp_query ) {
    global $current_user;
    if( is_admin() && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
        add_filter('views_edit-post', 'fix_post_counts');
        add_filter('views_upload', 'fix_media_counts');
    }
}
```